# onEdit along with IMPORTRANGE?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, importrange

I'm using the below script to capture the entry_timestamp of every new row that gets *imported* from a different Google Spreadsheet using the 'IMPORTRANGE' function.

```
function onEdit(e) {

    var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    if (ss.getName() !== 'Raw Data' || e.range.columnStart !== 3) return;
    e.range.offset(0, -2)
        .setValue(e.value ? new Date() : null);
}
```

While the above snippet works like charm every time I "edit" something in col.C, I would like the same functionality whenever a new line item gets inserted because of changes in the other spreadsheet which I'm reading using the IMPORTRANGE function.

Can any expert help me with that?  I have created a sample sheet for your reference here

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger a script when a formula changes a cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42815059/trigger-a-script-when-a-formula-changes-a-cell-value)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue, and found a solution.  Make a function called onChange, and set it up as a trigger to be fired on change for your spreadsheet.  This routine will fire when Importrange makes a change.

Edit: Sorry, it doesn't look like this is going to work because the event object for onChange doesn't give the information needed.