# Googlesheet script variable triggered only with manual cell input

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying something reasonably simple but can’t get it to work:

I want to hide multiple columns and/or rows based on the value of a cell.

I have it working with a simple script however it seems to only do its job when the trigger cell in question has the value input manually, i.e. I have a drop-down list of “0” & “1” and when I change it manually from “0” to “1” it all works.

However, the cell in question gets its value itself from a simple if condition and even though the value is, in the end, the same it seems the script is not working in such a case.

I would be grateful for any help.

That's the script I found online and is apart from not being triggered correctly in my case very useful:

```
//TITLE:
//Hide a row if a value is inputted.


//**GLOBALS**

// Sheet the data is on.
var SHEET = "TEST2";

// The value that will cause the row to hide. 
var VALUE = "1";

// The column we will be using 
var COLUMN_NUMBER = 1

function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();


  //Ensure on correct sheet.
  if(SHEET == activeSheet.getName()){
    var cell = ss.getActiveCell()
    var cellValue = cell.getValue();


    //Ensure we are looking at the correct column.
    if(cell.getColumn() == COLUMN_NUMBER){
      //If the cell matched the value we require,hide the row. 
      if(cellValue == VALUE){
        activeSheet.hideRow(cell);
      };
    };
  };
}
```

The cell(s) in question use this simple line:

```
=IF(INDIRECT("A4")=1,"0",IF(E10="NON-FACS",1,0))
```

Current outcome is: Nothing happens (except when input manually)

The expected outcome is: column number 1 should be hidden

Comment: Why not check for edits on A4 or E10 instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger a script when a formula changes a cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42815059/trigger-a-script-when-a-formula-changes-a-cell-value)