# How to fire a script when importrange changes a value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I have a spreadsheet where I grab a few cell with 'importrange'

When a such a cell changes I want to fire a script.

I've tried to use  'onEdit' but this only start the script when a user changes something inside the active sheet.
In my case a use changes something in a different spreadsheet.

Is there a way to detect in a script that the value of a cell is changed by importrange ?

Comment: Unfortunately, in your situation, the OnEdit event trigger cannot be used as you know. Although I'm not sure whether this is the direction you want, as a workaround, how about using the time-driven trigger? By the time-driven trigger, the specific cell can be monitored and the script can be run. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger a script when a formula changes a cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42815059/trigger-a-script-when-a-formula-changes-a-cell-value)