# Adding a Timestamp to a Google Sheet when the result of a cell using INDEX & MATCH changes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to add a timestamp when the result of a cell, which contains `INDEX` and `MATCH` formulae `(=INDEX('Sheet2'!$C$9:$Q$9,MATCH(I156,'Sheet2'!$C$5:$Q$5,1))`, changes. This forumula provides a numerical category/band for my different data entries (1, 2, 3 etc) depending on the number input in column `I`.

I ran the script below but it only works if I edit the cell itself and not if the formula result changes based on the value of column `I` changing.

I don't want to associate the script with the cells in column `I`, which I directly edit, as I want to track the date that my data moves from one category to another and the data in column `I` could change multiple times before it moves to the next category.

If anyone has some suggestions or links to articles that could help (I am a **complete novice**) - that would be great!

Thanks,

R

```
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();

  if (col === 5 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Master Test Sheet - All Stores") {
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,1).setValue(new Date());
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [How to automatically set date in a cell when a different cell value is changed by a formula from data on another sheet?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/130997/196152)

Comment: Ditto [Trigger a script when a formula changes a cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42827469/1330560)

Answer (score 0):

### `onEdit` does not track edits made by formulas

- The [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) trigger `onChange`, that can track SOME formula updates
- `INDEX` and `MATCH` are unfortunately not some of them, however `IMPORTRANGE` is
- Thus, you can implement the following workaround:

  - Make a new spreadsheet and import the cell with the `INDEX` and `MATCH` formula from your current spreadsheet with `=IMPORTRANGE`
  - Attach to the new spreadsheet a script and bind it to an `onChange` trigger
  - Specify within the script whatever you want to happen when the result of your formula updates